# How to retrieve class member in dojo/request promise

Tags: javascript, dojo

I use *dojo/reqeust* and *delcare* to make a test.

I declare a new class with a function which will use dojo/request to make a query. In the promise function, I can't retrieve the *this* member.

```
   var TestJson = declare(null, {
       name: "hello",
       doJson: function(){
          request.post("someTarget").then(function(res){
             alert(this.name);
          });
       }
  });

   var obj= new TestJson();
   obj.doJson();
```

As above, when post returned, the *alert(this.name)* invoked. But *this* points to the *Window* object, so *this.name* is undefined, not pointed to *TestJson.name*. So how can I retrieve TestJson.name? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can solve this problem.

Refer to a variable in the closure scope:

```
var TestJson = declare(null, {
  name: "hello",
  doJson: function(){
    var instance = this;
    request.post("someTarget").then(function(res){
      alert(instance.name);
    });
  }
});
```

Use the `dojo/_base/lang` module to [set the execution context](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/hitch/) on the callback:

```
var TestJson = declare(null, {
  name: "hello",
  doJson: function(){
    var callback = lang.hitch(this, function(res){
      alert(this.name);
    });
    request.post("someTarget").then(callback);
  }
});
```